# Checking If More Than One Different String Exists In A List

Tags: c#, vb.net

How can I print out all of names that are different from a Name property in an object called Person? I have a list of Person objects

```
Person.Name
Nick
Brit
BLANK
Nick
BLANK
Dog
Cat
```

I want to output all distinct names with excluding empty strings

```
Nick
Brit
Dog
Cat
```

Comment: do you have a list of persons, or is the property Names in your person object a list ?

Comment: I have a list of Person objects

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I'm not exactly sure how your code or program looks, but in order to get all distinct names across a list of persons, you first have to add each individual name to a list, and then select all the distinct ones.

this should do the trick:

```
var names = new List<string>();

foreach(var person in persons)
{
 if (!string.IsNullOrEmpty(person.Name))
 {
  names.Add(person.Name);
 }

}

var distinctNames = names.Distinct();
```

Comment: The only catch is that this is case-sensitive. If you have "Nick" and "nick" they will both be selected.

Comment: this will include empty entries (and OP asked "all distinct names with excluding empty strings")

Answer (score 3):

You could do it really nicely with LINQ:

```
List<string> distinctNames = people.Select(p => p.Name)
                                   .Where(n => !String.IsNullOrEmpty(n))
                                   .Distinct()
                                   .ToList();
```

Answer (score 1):

You could use a HashSet to keep track of the encountered names--something like this:

```
HashSet<string> nameSet = new HashSet<string>();

List<Person> persons = getPersonList(); // get the list somehow

foreach (Person p in persons) {
  string name = p.Name;
  if (!string.IsNullOrEmpty(name)) {
    if (!nameSet.Contains(name)) {
      nameSet.Add(name);
    }
  }
}

List<string> names = nameSet.ToArray();
foreach (string name in names) {
  Console.WriteLine(name);
}
```

EDIT: call this the "C# 2.0 version."  The LINQ answers are much more elegant.

Comment: Gotta get me some of this LINQ stuff!

Comment: Early on I ignored LINQ because it seemed complicated, but once I learned it, it saved me so much time and made several piece of code look more elegant. I highly suggest you check it out.

Answer (score 1):

You can also accomplish this with LINQ

```
var DistinctNames = persons.Where(w => !String.IsNullOrEmpty(w.Name))
                           .Select(s => s.Name).Distinct();
```

This will give you an `IEnumerable` of string. If you want to print them out on a console window, you can use

```
persons.Where(w => !String.IsNullOrEmpty(w.Name)) 
                          .Select(s => s.Name)
                          .Distinct().ToList()
                          .ForEach(f => Console.WriteLine(f.Name));
```

This uses the `List` `ForEach`, which isn't the best practice, depending on who you ask, but it's a simple one line to do a simple thing.